# How to add a timedelta to a timezone aware timestamp and take into account day time saving dst

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, dst, pytz

I have a datetime.datetime object:

```
my_timestamp = datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 1, 0, 0)
```

To make it timezone aware ('Europe/Amsterdam') I use:

```
import pytz    
my_datetime = pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam').localize(my_timestamp)
```

Which returns to me the correct timestamp in the correct timezone (CET):

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
```

Now I need to add a timedelta/dateoffset (not sure about terminology) of three months. I use:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta    
my_datetime_with_offset = my_datetime + relativedelta(months = 3)
```

Which returns to me:

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
```

However, I would like it to take into account day time saving (dst). Instead of the above tz (CET), I would like to get the following object (tz = CEST):

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

I found a way to find my goal:

```
#1. make timestamp
my_datetime = pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam').localize(datetime(2022, 2, 1, 0, 0))
# #2. save timezone information
my_tz = my_datetime.tzinfo
# #3. make offset to naive datetimeobject
my_datetime_with_offset = my_datetime.replace(tzinfo=None) + relativedelta(months = 3)
# 4. convert back to timezone aware timestmap
my_datetime_with_offset = my_tz.localize(my_datetime_with_offset)
 ## This works.
```

However, this feels like a workarounjd. I suspect there must be a more proper way to do this (I am using datetime.datetime, pytz and dateutils all at the same time). Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

ASNSWER as suggested by FObersteiner:

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # standardpackage
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

my_datetime = datetime(2022, 2, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("Europe/Amsterdam"))
my_datetime = my_datetime + relativedelta(months =3)
```

Will get the tz correct after adding relativedelta.

HOWEVER, it should be noted that this solution is not compatible YET with pandas (1.4.4). Sticking to the older pytz convention the following can be used:

```
my_datetime_with_offset = my_tz.normalize(my_datetime + relativedelta(months = 3))
```

Comment: pytz is deprecated. use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) or [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).